# make image fill remaining vertical space, no scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a page with a title, paragraph and a single image, that can be of very different sizes/aspect ratios.

I would like the image to adapt so that it will either fill maximum available height, or be limited by its width, without loosing aspect ratio, neither causing scrolling.

this is my basic config:

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" layout="column" layout-fill> 
  <div flex style="background: red;">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Details. Blablabla.</p> 
  </div>
  <div flex="60" style="background: blue;" object-fit="fill">
    <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/200x400"/>
    <!-- Should work with such extreme case as well -->
    <!-- <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/1000x200" /> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I have looked at a lot of SO posts, websites, blogs, etc. I can't figure out where to start to get this done. Most articles about fluid images or responsive images only talk about scrollable web pages. So even a good reference on the topic would be helpful. Thank you.

EDIT: Updated the snipped to use [flex layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children). As you can see, the image goes outside the blue div bounds. I have used `object-fit="content";` or `object-fit="fill";` but none seems to constraint the image to respect div bounds

Comment: Here's a jquery trick to get image dimensions, after getting dimensions you can compare the width and height for the larger of the two, then set the appropriate image attribute (ie, width or height) - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-an-images-native-width/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)([it doesn't support IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)) and css [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)([it supports most of broswer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)).

> What did you do?

I wrap image by a div(`.wrapper`), calculate height of it by css `calc`.

```
height: calc(100vh - 19px - 38px); //100% of viewport - height of p - height of h1
```

and then use `object-fit` to image is fitted the height of `.wrapper` by keeping the ration of image.

**Image by high height**

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"]);
```

```css
h1,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 19px - 38px);
}
img {
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style-parent>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Details. Blablabla.</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/200x400" /> 
    <!-- Should work with such extreme case as well -->
    <!-- <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/1000x200" /> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Image by less height**

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"]);
```

```css
h1,
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 19px - 38px);
}
img {
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style-parent>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Details. Blablabla.</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/200x400" />  -->
    <!-- Should work with such extreme case as well -->
    <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/1000x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is quite helpful. However, I am looking for a more generic solution rather than having to compute height by hand. Do you know if object-fit only works when containing div has absolute sizes only ?

Comment: I have updated my snippet to use vertical flex layout, the issue is that the image, despite using object-fit, is not respecting div-bounds. Any clue why ?

Comment: @Overdrivr I'm sorry to replay late. I'm not familiar by `flex` but you have to give `object-fit` to the image and its container must have height.

Answer (score 1):

I would use css properties like "background-size:cover". Here is an example. First 2 containers use the "cover" approach on 2 containers with different aspect ratio without altering the image ratio. The third one uses "pixel dimensions". Remember that if u alter either x or y axis dimensions do only so on one of them and define the other as auto in order to not alter the image ratio(like hover effect does on third container).

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/0111sfmg/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container1">
</div>
<br>
<div class="container2">
</div>
<br>
<div class="container3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container1 {
    background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid green;
}
.container2 {
    background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:600px;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid green;
}
.container3 {
    background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid green;
}

.container3:hover {

    background-size: 450px auto;

}
```

You can define this in your stylesheet, inline, inside custom directive, ng-style or whatever suits you best.

Browser support:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but in case anybody else is having troubles with the same situation, the problem is that the father container needs to be a flex container, in order to give boundaries to its children:

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc7/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" layout="column" layout-fill> 
  <div flex style="background: red;">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Details. Blablabla.</p> 
  </div>
  <div flex="60" style="background: blue;display: flex" object-fit="fill">
    <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/200x400"/>
    <!-- Should work with such extreme case as well -->
    <!-- <img id="myImg" ng-src="http://placehold.it/1000x200" /> -->
  </div>
</div>
```